# How to Detect if Assistive Access is turned on in iOS 17

Tags: ios, accessibility, ios17

Is there a way to programmatically determine the status of Accessibility Assistive Access on iOS 17? I want to be able to adjust the app's behavior or interface based on whether these accessibility features are enabled or not.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to query it.  You have to design your app so that it will work properly when Assistive Access is turned on.  Check out this Apple video from WWDC23 about this feature - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10032/

At 5:25 it talks about how to adjust your app to work with Assistive Access.  You need to add `UISupportsFullscreenInAssistiveAccess` to your info.plist and then it refers to various properties you can set to adjust the layout of your app.

This is still a very new feature so there aren't many resources outside of Apple that help.

The video refers to a few other resources from WWDC in 2022 and 2018

- WWDC22 - Composing Custom Layouts with Swiftui

  - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/composing_custom_layouts_with_swiftui
  - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10056/ (video)
- WWDC18 - UIKit: Apps for Every Size and Shape

  - https://nilotic.github.io/2018/09/19/UIKit-Apps-for-Every-Size-and-Shape.html
  - https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc18/235/ (notes)
  - https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2018/235gkyrtsva0gy/235/235_uikit_apps_for_every_size_and_shape.pdf (pdf)

Comment: It seems Apple's apps are somehow tailored to Assistive Access. For example, a much simpler keyboard, much larger fonts. I enabled this Info.plist key and ran my app in Assistive Access mode, but it just looks normal, except there is a gigantic back button at the bottom. I doubt a cognitive disabled person can understand the "normal" mode of my app. I think Assistive Access is a good idea but we devs should have an API that tells us when to present a suitable UI.

Comment: @bio I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I even think Assistive Access paves the way for an entirely new UI style API in SwiftUI. Like, a completely simplified iPadOS/iOS L&F. An easy mode if you will, for old people who can’t read well and just need the basics. Could deserve its own target in an Xcode project.